Resistance vs Capacity in Building a Power Bank
I am building a power bank consisting of "12" 18650 cells arranged as 3 set of 4 in parallel and then putting the 3 sets in series to achieve 12.6 V more or less.
My questions are:

do I match the cells in the 4 parallel section by resistance or by capacity, and
do I need the 3 packs of 4 to have similar resistance or similar capacity.


All the cells should be matched.

Are you asking this because you want to get out the most of the cells in terms of current capability and capacity?
If the cells are unprotected/you don't have charging supervision this is likely to start a fire... just saying

Here is an online tool once you have ESR and capacity for each cell: https://cellsaviors.com/pack-builder

In principle, you want the currents between paralleled cells to be matched, so you want matched resistance across each parallel section.
In principle, you want each series block to have the same capacity, to keep the charge/discharge voltage change balanced between the seriesed blocks.
In practice, if you can measure a significant imbalance between multiple cells, either resistance or capacity, then you should not really be building them into a multi-cell battery at all.

Thank you for the clear and concise explanation
